# FileZilla often fails or corrupt files during upload?

Tags: macos, ftp

According to the documentation for http://simple-press.com:

> Note that this plugin is big! Use a reliable tool to upload it to your
>   server. Please note that FileZilla often fails or corrupt files during
>   upload. Please avoid using it.

I'm completely unaware of anything like this. Is it true, and if so, what's better (on OSX)?

Comment: Googling for `mac ftp` yields Transmit, Cyberduck and Fetch on page 1, which are, AFAICT, the most popular OS X FTP clients, as well as Yummy FTP (I don't like it, YMMV) and Interarchy. Let's focus on the part regarding FileZilla reliability, not on alternatives. That's the easy part.

Comment: I'm not wondering about alternatives on OSX, @DanielBeck, I'm wondering it they're better in this regard :)

Comment: Also, the thing is 3.4mb. I'm not sure what kind of experiences they've had with FileZilla, but I've had only good (but ugly) ones...

Comment: In all the gigabytes I've transferred using Filezilla, I don't recall a single instance of corruption.

Comment: @Amazed, plus I think it's the most likely to give you a clear idea of what's still pending transfer if the connection breaks. Not sure what kind of bad Saturday morning these guys had once-upon-a-time :)

Comment: Binary transfer types have always been more reliable that ASCII transfer types in any FTP program, IMHO.